# Compactness of the convergent to zero sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

I've gotta prove that

$$T = \left\{ \left\{ x_i \right\} \in {\ell ^\infty }:\left| x_i \right| < \mu_i,\mathop \lim\limits_{i \to \infty } \mu _i = 0 \right\} \subseteq \ell ^\infty $$

is compact.
I'm just kind of sure that i've got to use sequential compactness, but i don't even know where to start.

Comment: What do open and closed sets look like in $\mathcal{l}^\infty$?

Comment: $T$ is not even closed. You have to impose $|x_i| \leq \mu_i$ instead of $|x_i| < \mu_i$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, the set $T$ is not closed, but 
$$\left\{ \left\{ x_i \right\} \in {\ell ^\infty }:\left| x_i \right| \leqslant \mu_i,\mathop \lim\limits_{i \to \infty } \mu _i = 0 \right\}$$
is. We can show that it is precompact by fixing $\varepsilon$. We then take $N$ such that $|\mu_i|\lt\varepsilon$ if $i\geqslant N+1$ and we use compactness of the set $\prod_{i=1}^N[-\mu_i,\mu_i]$ in $\mathbb R^N$.